Passing parameters in a GET method using Volley library in Android
I am using the following url for a GET request:
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/v1/user/login?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
It looks like the user may choose a username / password such that it will cause the url to have different meaning in terms of the parameter names and values.
For example: I have noticed that if username = "&" and password = 1 then the login request returns false.
I have tried passing parameters using the following code:
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

But this method does not work with GET requests.
Is there anyway to encapsulate the variables in the url string? Or should I change the method in the server to a POST method?

NEVER put login parameters in a GET request.  Always use POST.  The reason is that the password is then in the URL with a GET, making it public to any router in between, in your logs, visible to anyone packet sniffing the network, etc.  This also avoids the problem you mention, because POST values don't have the same encoding issues.

Thank you. But isn’t this against the concept of GET / POST difference? Login request doesn’t add any new record to the database, and only accesses existing data.

You're taking too literal a view of GET/POST to a specific way of using it.  GET/POST don't need to have anything to do with a database.  But look at any discussion of security in web services, and they will all say that GET should never be used if there's information that needs to be secured.

GET is also limited to only 256 characters (the max length of a URL).  So it is very normal to use POST even for information requests.
