Making an activity show up only when onCreate method is finished
I have a web server hosted on railway app and as a result when I load up an activity it usually takes like half a second for the UI elements to be filled with the current information from the server.
While onCreate is running, I see on the screen the static layout UI elements which are used as placeholders to visualize the design.
How can I set the activity to show nothing (white screen) until onCreate is finished running?

Two things here.
1)onCreate needs to be FAST.  Nothing should be waiting on the UI thread.  If it takes more than a few dozen milliseconds, you're doing it wrong.  The UI thread should never be waiting for anything, and if it needs to wait you need to re-architect your app to do it asynchronously.
2)onCreate doesn't draw before it's finished.  That's because for the UI to draw, the framework needs to process an invalidate message.  For it to process the message, the UI thread needs to be idle.  This means onCreate needs to return, so the looper hidden inside the framework can process the next message in its queue.  If it doesn't return, it can't process the message and nothing can draw.
So your app isn't doing what you think its doing.  And without significant code, we can't help you.

yes I’m sorry onCreate method indeed finishes running within few dozen milliseconds. I have asynchronous Volley requests inside the onCreate which finish running after half a second. I’m thinking setting all the activity page to white background, until the server method finishes. Is there a quick way to do it (Instead of View.INVISIBLE to all)

Generally you put up a spinner or some other loading screen or other UI to show the user that it's working.  And yes, swapping the loading screen vs content from VISIBLE to INVISIBLE is a normal way of doing it

Thank you, fixed my problem. Btw if you are familiar with Volley library, can you help me with a simple question that I asked on another post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78887229/passing-parameters-in-a-get-method-using-volley-library-in-android
